# The field of a Data source has a forward slash '/' as part of the name. How do I include it in Power Apps Gallery using ThisItem?

Tags: escaping, special-characters, powerapps

In PowerApps, I'm using a data source from a SharePoint list that has a forward slash as part of the field name.  For example, there is a column named 'Edit/Rework'.  I have a Gallery in PowerApps where I'm trying to assign that column to the 'text' property of a label via ThisItem.'Edit/Rework'.  PowerApps gives an error "This formula uses scope, which is not presently supported for evaluation"  How do you specify a column that contains a / in it?  Is there an escape character that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the forward slash / is not an issue.  Just needed to specify .DisplayName after the field.  ThisItem.'Lead/Mgr'.DisplayName